# Will a BackgroundService always run in a new Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core-3.0

So in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks) for ASP.Net Core it shows you how to create Background Tasks with hosted services. There is even a specific paragraph which explains how you can create a Background Queue.

Now my question is, will the `ExecuteAsync` method run in its own thread already, or do I need to call `Task.Run` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will the `ExecuteAsync` method run in its own thread

Presuming `ExecuteAsync` is an `async` method (`public async Task ExecuteAsync`)

Tl;Dr it depdends

`async` means that this thread can be `await`ed. `await` will park the current execution of the main thread until the result of the `async` returns. This will release the current thread back into the thread pool for re-use. Then when the `async` returns a new thread (maybe depending on how you actually call this) is pulled out of the thread pool to continue execution. This is called context switching.

If this method is not truly `async` then nothing really happens, it run as if it's not an `async` method.

If this method explicitly creates a `Task` (using `Task.Run`) then the `async` thread will `await` this `Task`. So the Task uses a new thread and the `async` method will release it's thread and get a new one when the Task returns. This isn't a zero sum though as the context switching is expensive. This is why you should only `async` [IO bound methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58667131/542251) as you typically loose efficiency not gain in CPU bound processes.

I'd suggest you read [Stephen Cleary's excellent blogs on the subject](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Comment: There is no answer on main question: will HostedService always run in separate thread or not?

Comment: The answer to the main question, is **it depends** as I stated in my answer @DenisBabarykin. Will it **always** run, [as stated below, no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59031056/542251)

Answer (score 7):

**`Will a BackgroundService always run in a new Thread?` No.**

`BackgroundService` doesn't specify anything about threading. The only thing it asks is for an overload that returns a `Task`, that remains active as long as the service is up. You can even return a *completed* task if you want.

If you [check the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/aa7fa91cfc8f6ff078b020a428bcad71ae7a32ab/src/Hosting/Abstractions/src/BackgroundService.cs#L13) you'll see that there's no assumption at all :

```
    protected abstract Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken);

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

The threading behavior of the service method is up to the implementor, ie you. If `ExecuteAsync` blocks before yielding, the entire service blocks. If the method never yields, the call to `StartAsync` itself will block and cause problems for the entire application.

If `ExecuteAsync` does something expensive before the first `await`, starting other services will be delayed as well.

This means that you may need to use `Task.Run` if the service needs to do anything expensive before yielding for the first time, ie the first call to `await`.

Answer (score 1):

From [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

> For I/O-bound code, you await an operation which returns a Task or
> Task inside of an async method.
>
> For CPU-bound code, you await an operation which is started on a
> background thread with the Task.Run method.

So if your `ExecuteAsync` method is **I/O-bound** (it looks like it is I/O-bound by its name) then you do not need to call `Task.Run`

But when the method is **CPU-bound**(i.e. your code be performing a computation), then you should call `Task.Run` to run in background

Comment: Well should't I do `Task.Run` inside the Enqueued item then?

Comment: the answer is No

Comment: Well why not, when the task which is enqueued is not CPU Bound, it would be useless to call `Task.Run`?

Comment: It will be useless if you use Task.Run for any async method